# webrequest handing error 502 and 500 in c#

Tags: c#, json, webrequest

I am building a project using c# that should get some JSON information from a website, then do certain process on it. Generally it works 80% of the times, but the remaining 20% I get Error 500 or Error 502 or even empty JSON file which I don't know how to handle. I handled the Empty JSON with a timer method (try again after x time) . However, error 500 and 502 still annoying me!

here is my Code, appreciating any suggestions:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.********.ca/api******/status");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Timeout = 5000;

        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
            sr.Close();
        }
        textBox2.Text = text;

    }
```

Thank you!

Edit: solved: 
I solved it with the help of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ...

```
    if (response.StatusCode.ToString() != "OK")
```

((Basically anything other then code:200) => try again after X time -using timer method-, limited to Y number of trials)

Comment: Some remarks: `sr.Close()` is not needed the `using` will take care ot this. `500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.` and `502 Bad Gateway: The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.`   are both communication errors that you could handle the same as your empty response - by trying again. See f.e.[here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for status code explanations.

Comment: you might need a limit on retries in case the server never delivers anything than those codes though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you... I solved it with the help of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ... `if (response.StatusCode.ToString() != "OK")` ((Anything other then code:200) => try again after X time, limited to Y number of trials) ...it's working well till now. Hopefully, it will stay like that.